# Rails database from MySQL to Postgres

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I developed a ROR application using MySQL and now want it to use Postgres instead.

I've used Navicat to data transfer the MySQL database to Postgres, and updated the database.yml with the Postgres environment settings.

When I run the ROR application, and try and login or create a user, I get the following error:

> RuntimeError: ERROR   C23502  Mnull value in column "id" violates not-null constraint FexecMain.c L2229   RExecConstraints: INSERT INTO "users

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you had an AUTO_INCREMENT `id` column in your MySQL database. This is a non-ANSI-standard feature, so it won't necessarily work on other databases.

To do the same on Postgres you could use a [SERIAL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/interactive/datatype.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL) column type (or an equivalent explicit SEQUENCE).

Comment: How do I fix this, Is it something in the code I need to change or in the database, or both? Thank you

Comment: This worked:

ALTER TABLE users
    ALTER COLUMN id set DEFAULT NEXTVAL('users_id_seq')